# Good NAS box with lots of storage and performance

Tags: network-attached-storage

Looking for a good quality NAS box with good storage and performance.

Need to to be HA and so RAID and replication are required features.

Also is it is able to take version backup like Windows Shadow copy this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Budget? space requirements? physical size? interfaces? protocols? Bueller? Bueller? Bueller?

Comment: About 20TB, rack mount, 1GB interfaces with teaming, Quoters would be good, TCPIP, Windows servers will be connecting to it to map network drives and access shares authenticated using local DB on NAS

Comment: Ok, well that sounds more like Thecus/QNAP territory then rather than say NetApp. Take a look at

Comment: Sorry- Take a look at what?

Comment: http://www.thecus.com/product_catalog.php?PROD_TYPE_ID=11 or http://qnap.com/Products.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/) is an option?

Comment: Not really a Linux man.

Comment: So you know, this is a GUI driven NAS solution - both installation and administration. It is also feature rich. If you're concerned about implementing a technology you are unfamiliar with I understand.

Answer (score 1):

A PogoLinux storage array based on NexentaStor and ZFS: http://www.pogostorage.com/products/nexenta/overview/index.php

Comment: This really is a fantastic option.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Paul above - [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org) - I have used it at home with some old hardware/drives, RAID5 - and had great luck with it. It's very robust, with many different configurations/setups.

Answer (score 0):

Built a similar box for backups using a Norco case and freenas.  Most everything storage is some form of linux with a gui.  Freenas is no different.  Freenas 8 has made some big upgrades.  Nexenta is great too, but more expensive.